# How to check if message has attachments (MailKit)

Tags: c#, .net, imap

I'm using IMAP4 client called: MailKit.

It works great, but I have a problem knowing whether the message has attachments or not.

I've tried:

```
var summary = inbox.Fetch(MessageId,MessageSummaryItems.Body,cancel.Token).FirstOrDefault();  
var bodyMultiPart = summary.Body as BodyPartMultipart;
if (bodyMultiPart != null)
{
   foreach (var bodyPart in bodyMultiPart.BodyParts.Where(x => x is BodyPartBasic))
   {
        BodyPartBasic basicPart = bodyPart as BodyPartBasic;
        if (basicPart.ContentDisposition != null && basicPart.ContentDisposition.IsAttachment)
        {
           //add basic part as attachment
        }               
   }    
}
```

But for some messages (for example: message that has PDF as attachment) the content disposition is **null**.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure instead of MessageSummaryItems.Body.

BODYSTRUCTURE retrieves more details for each body part than BODY does. I think that the Content-Disposition header is one of the extra things that BODYSTRUCTURE retrieves over plain BODY.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What makes you think that something should be considered an attachment which is not being considered an attachment via the logic you pasted above?

Comment: I've messages with a PDF file attached which only sometimes considered as having attachments. The behavior of MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure is not consistent.

Comment: If it's not consistent, then it means the server is inconsistent or the sending mailing client is inconsistent. Take a look at the raw message source - does the pdf attachment have a Content-Disposition header? Does it say that it is an attachment?

Comment: Keep in mind that the logic you are using to determine if a MIME part is an attachment or not is based on the Content-Disposition header existing *and* having a value of "attachment" (as opposed to "inline" or any other value). This is just a heuristic. You can use any heuristic you want, but generally speaking, this is the heuristic that mail clients use (they also show MIME parts that they can't render as attachments).

Answer (score 0):

When the content disposition is null, you can use the content type as a hint: text/* is seldom an attachment, multipart/* is not a hint, other types generally hint at attachments.

PDF is application/pdf, so that's an attachment according to this heuristic.

Comment: Usually something isn't considered an attachment unless it has a Content-Disposition header with a value of "attachment" and/or if the client itself doesn't know how to render the part content.